Pandas interpretation question with double quotes in csv
I have a csv file whose values are comma separated.
One of the values of a column in plain text is inputted as
"XATO,2xASSY,SSD, 6.4TB Gen2, SFF-2.5"", N"

which is supposed be within double quotes so that the comma inside the value is not mistaken as a separator.
And when I do pd.read_csv and then print this value, I am getting
XATO,2xASSY,SSD, 6.4TB Gen2, SFF-2.5", N

as the result. Which is exactly what I need, but I just can't seem to understand the interpretation logic. Why is the second last double quote getting omitted by default in pandas.read_csv ?
Edit: one can put first string in a csv file, using a text editor (not Excel) and then open the file in Excel or read the csv using pandas and see the output.
Answer: I think pandas is reading it as the concatenation of 2 strings 'XATO,2xASSY,SSD, 6.4TB Gen2, SFF-2.5"' + ', N'.

In that case, I can't reproduce your output. assert pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('"XATO,2xASSY,SSD, 6.4TB Gen2, SFF-2.5"", N"'), doublequote=False).columns.to_list() == ['XATO,2xASSY,SSD, 6.4TB Gen2, SFF-2.5"', ' N"']. Can you show a complete file input example and the exact code you used, as well as the complete output you got?

I am just doing pd.read_csv(filename, date_format={'DATA_LABEL': '%Y%m%d'}, escapechar='\\') and print(df['ITEM_DESCRIPTION'])

Edit: OP had a typo and apparently the answer below is not relevant. Leaving it here for the sake of other readers who might be interested. Stand by for an updated answer.

Pandas is looking for the longest quoted region between double-quote characters ".
That is, when Pandas encounters a " that is a candidate for the beginning of a field, it searches rightward for a matching " to close the field. However it does not close the field immediately when it first encounters a second ". Instead, it searches for the outermost instance of " that is followed by whitespace and another field separator ,, or by the end of the line.
Note that this behavior will also be affected by the doublequote= kwarg, which defaults to True, and by the quoting= kwarg, which defaults to csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL.
With doublequote=False and quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, the input "XATO,2xASSY,SSD, 6.4TB Gen2, SFF-2.5""""""", N" produces the outputs XATO,2xASSY,SSD, 6.4TB Gen2, SFF-2.5"""""" and N". All of the "s except the rightmost are considered part of the field contents.
By comparison, "XATO,2xASSY,SSD, 6.4TB Gen2, SFF-2.5"","""""", N" parses out to three columns, XATO,2xASSY,SSD, 6.4TB Gen2, SFF-2.5", """, and  N".
Expressed as regex, the behavior is conceptually similar to "(.*?)"(?:,|$), where the field contents themselves are the 1st capture group. Whether it's actually implemented by backtracking or other means, I don't know. You'd have to check the source code for that. And of course the actual behavior is significantly more complicated than what you would want to attempt to express in plain regex.
